# rerender a react server component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, websocket, mqtt

I am working on a next.js/react.js app.

I have a component tree, such as below:

// server comp
 // client component

I have an MQTT connection on parent component.... If it is a client component, it gives error. Therefore, I need it to be server comp, which means I cannot use useState or other hooks.

The code is as belows, basically (simplified)

```
import * as mqtt from "mqtt";

const socket_client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://xxxxx:xxxx");

socket_client.on("connect", () => {
  //console.log("in connect:", socket_client);
  socket_client.subscribe("nodered", function (err) {
    console.log("connected/subscribed");
  });
});

export default function Test() {
  let data = "";

  let reRender = 1;
  console.log("reRender:", reRender);

  socket_client.on("message", (topic, message) => {
    let payload = { topic, message: message.toString() };
    data = message.toString();
    console.log("in /nodered/Test, data: ", data);
    reRender++;
  });

  return (
    <section>
      <div className="flex flex-col" key={reRender}>
        <TestClient key={reRender} render={reRender} data={data} />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

I need "TestClient" to be rerendered, therefore, whenever there is a new message from MQTT connection, the props will be updated and therefore I will be able to use the props.data in TestClient...
However, the reRender value is not updated, since that I cannot use useState (tried with useState, rerendered with changing reRender but this time MqTT doesnt work correctly).

note:
I can see the MQTT connection works fine and the message is updated on a publish from node-red. Son no problem... But need this data to passed to childcomp, whenever it is updated.

note-2:
I tried to put key in both div and childcomp props... both did not work.

Question:

1. is there any way to force rerender TestClient
2. any options to get mqtt data... But, tried a lot, it doesnt work fine in client comps.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
I might have found a possible solution. Wrapping a server component in the client component as below ex.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns

```
// This pattern works:
// client component

'use client'
 
import { useState } from 'react'
 
export default function ClientComponent({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
 
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
      {children}
    </>
  )
}
// You can pass a Server Component as a child or prop of a
// Client Component.
import ClientComponent from './client-component'
import ServerComponent from './server-component'
 
// Pages in Next.js are Server Components by default
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <ClientComponent>
      <ServerComponent />
    </ClientComponent>
  )
}
```

however, this time I need to pass data from ServerComponent to ClientComponent. How can I do this? Thanks